# How to restart nautilus without logging out?

Tags: nautilus

How do I just restart the nautilus after adding a nautilus script without having to log out.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

To restart nautilus...

- First, type the following in your terminal to quit nautilus:

  `nautilus -q` or `killall nautilus`
- Then, open nautilus via Unity menu (press the Super key) or using the run command (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without starting a nautilus window? As in it would be running and display a desktop without bringing it's own window.

Comment: if nautilus crashes, which happens quite easily in 12.04, then your desktop items are gone. This does not help to bring them back permanently. As soon as you close nautilus, the desktop is empty once more.

Comment: +1 for `killall nautilus` it should be first solution

Answer (score 45):

Open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and try this:

```
$ nautilus -q && nautilus &
```

get it done without switching from the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I had a GTK error at one point and nautilus -q did not work. So instead of asking nicely I went a more ridiculous route to kill nautilus and restart.

`$ ps -aux | grep nautilus`

This will list all processes that have nautilus in description. You should get something like this.

carlos    2070  0.1  0.9 1608528 77500 ?       Sl   08:56   0:40 nautilus -n

carlos   29272  0.0  0.0  16744  1004 pts/1    S+   16:38   0:00 grep --color=auto nautilus

Look for the one with that says nautilus and grab the 4 digit code. Once you have that written down you can kill the process.

`$ sudo kill 2070`

Nautilus should die and restart automatically. Again I just used this because I had a wierd GTK error when I tried running nautilus -q.

Comment: FYI, what you did is the same as using `killall nautilus` from the accepted answer.  It finds all processes with the executable named "nautilus" and kills them.  Helpful when you know the process's executable name.  But if you're ever unsure, you should do a `ps -aux | grep <executable>` to make sure that you will kill the right process.

Comment: Am I confused or did you simply kill a `grep` process that was already done? Didn't you want to kill process 2070? And you own the process so you don't need sudo

Comment: @JimLohse yes. Blast. Thank you for spotting that error. I just updated my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Another option without terminal is by closing "Nautilus" from "System Monitor" .