# How to set the desktop to $HOME/Desktop?

Tags: gnome

Recently I deleted the folder `Desktop` from my `$HOME` directory. When I logged in again all files and directories in `$HOME` were shown on the desktop. So I wanted to get the folder back. What is the recommended way to achieve this? I edited `~/.config/xdg-user-dirs.dir` and added the correct variable. But I guess there must be some other (more easy?) way.

Comment: install ubuntu tweak 0.5, there is a Section under "Desktop" category called "Desktop icon settings",simply uncheck the "Show content of home folder on desktop..." and logout

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. **Create a new folder that you want to use as your folder.**

   For example, type `mkdir ~/Desktop` in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open one) to create a folder named Desktop in your home directory.
2. **Edit your configuration.**

   Edit the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. You can do this by opening a terminal, then enter:

   ```
   gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
   ```

   Change the entry for `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` to your new desktop folder, or add it, if the entry does not exist. After your edit, the file should look like this:

   ```
   XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"  
   XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Download"  
   XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"  
   XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"  
   XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"  
   XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"  
   XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"  
   XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
   ```
3. **Log out and then log in again** and your desktop should show the specified folder.

Comment: If you don't want to logout the following appears to work in gnome-shell/nautilus (tested in Centos 7) after modifying the file. `nautilus -q && nautilus &` Here's another [question][1] for reference. [1]:http://askubuntu.com/questions/19979/how-to-restart-nautilus-without-logging-out

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xdg-user-dirs-update` command to set `Desktop`.

```
 xdg-user-dirs-update --set DESKTOP $HOME/NewDesktop
```

But at first check out your locale names

```
 cat  ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

For English locale they are:

```
 XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
 XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
 XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
 XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
 XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
 XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
 XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
 XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

You can set any of the above

```
 xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD ~/Internet
```

in order for the changes to take effect `nautilus -q`.

For more info check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories

Answer (score 1):

In my case after updating `gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` was not worked. Because there was as symbolic link '../Desktop' in system and that had been broken (i think after update). I simply deleted that symbolic link and created new directory and edited `gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Answer (score 0):

Just create an new folder with the name Desktop.

Comment: I forgot to mention this. This was my first try and it didn't work. Logged out of my GNOME session and after logging in again I had all icons on the screen as before (plus the new Desktop folder).

Comment: @qbi: And what if you add a folder named 'Desktop', but in **your native language**? GNOME likes to play around with translated folder names.

Comment: This I took for granted.