# home/user/Desktop and Public Folders Show as Type Link (broken) (inode/symlink)

Tags: permissions, symbolic-link, hard-link

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS asked me for an update which I did and apparently everything went ok but upon restarting all my home folders appeared in my Desktop.

Looking into my home folder I found out that **home/user/Desktop** and **Public** folders show as: **Type Link (broken) (inode/symlink)**. The rest of user folders have different permissions ("Create and delete files") but this file only gives me the options of "Read and write" an "Read-only".

By doing `ls -lid` to these files as suggested by Raffa, I get:

```
1334600 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 19 ago 19 11:40 Desktop -> /home/user/Desktop
```

and

```
1334614 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 18 ago 19 11:40 Public -> /home/user/Public
```

How can I fix this?

I'm currently on 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: The output of `ls -lid /home/$USER/{Desktop,Public}` might help us see part of the picture.

Comment: Thanks, added that output to the question.

Comment: I applied an UBUNTU UPDATE yesterday and this morning I rebooted my system and found all my home folders as desktop icons.  I never have DESKTOP ICONS displayed.  I downloaded the Extension Manager app and was able to hide these desktop icons and then I noticed the same thing that is indicated on this ticket.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Is there any update?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the Desktop is now pointing at the Home directory.

Comment: @Gigiux Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I don't know, I was hoping you knew...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it this way:

As suggested by https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=198238 I checked that typing

```
cat $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs | grep DESKTOP
```

showed

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
```

instead of

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

Then I followed this solution [How to set the desktop to $HOME/Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116276/how-to-set-the-desktop-to-home-desktop)

1. First I deleted all the broken folders

```
rm Desktop Templates Public Music Videos
```

2. I created new folders

```
mkdir Desktop Templates Public Music Videos
```

3. Then I edited configuration file: Typing in the terminal

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

I added the missing folders to make it look like this:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop" 
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Download"  
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"  
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"  
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"  
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"  
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"  
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

4. Save the configuration file, and after logging out and in the problem was solved

Comment: Worked for me too. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much. Did this and everything is back to normal :)

Comment: Further on this: the link go back to broken at log-out even if ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs is fine. So I need to remove and recreate the folder over and over...

Comment: Actually, in one machine, the `user-dirs.dirs` file erases Desktop and Public each time I log out...

Comment: I did this, but later on restart, the link was broken again as before. Any idea which program is resetting these folders?

Comment: I changed the permissions of user-dirs.dirs to allow other users read only access `chmod o+rw ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and set the owner to root `chown root:root ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. You could try that @hkbharath

Comment: Now I also lost `Downloads`

Answer (score 2):

Adding this as an answer, as I cannot comment yet.

I bumped into the same issue, and I was lucky enough to remember that the only change I made to my system today was to install [Okular](https://github.com/KDE/okular) (as a Snap via the `Ubuntu Software` app).

The fix above works fine, as long as I don't open Okular. If I do, and then reboot, I am back to square one.

Note that another user is suggesting that [adding hidden files to the folders prevents this from happening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488100/okular-breaking-home-directories-links).

I cannot find any mention of this bug in the KDE bug tracker, so maybe I'll try to add a new one in the coming days. I hope this helps.

Comment: Did you install it as a snap?

Comment: I did. I will update the message.

Comment: Further on this, I had to reinstall Ubuntu to fix this problem. Today I used Okular for the first time and the issue came back...