# Okular breaking /home directories links

Tags: 20.04, pdf, okular

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 version and I had recently installed Okular for manage and editing .pdf files. Since I installed and ran this program the /home/Music /home/Videos /home/Public and /home/Templates directories links were broken (see [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqhl0.png)). When I try to enter one of these directories this message appears: "The link "Music" is broken. Move it to trash?"

I tried to delete this directories, create new ones and add the path in the /home/.config/user-dirs.dirs file and it worked. I restarted the PC and all the directories where fine, but when I turned on the PC on the next day and opened Okular the problem appear again.

Could anyone show me something I could try to solve this issue? Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Home directories turned into symbolic links without telling me the reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482903/home-directories-turned-into-symbolic-links-without-telling-me-the-reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I found a solution for the Okular issue. I noticed that the directories where Okular was breaking the links where empty, so I decided to create some hidden files on that directories and after that the problem was solved. It is not a definitive solution but at least now the directories are available.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this trouble, in my case on Ubuntu 22.04, I resolved by installing Okular from the terminal instead of the Ubuntu Software app.