# Iomega Home Media Network Hard Drive 1TB Cloud Edition failed, data recovery?

Tags: hardware, cloud, data-recovery, ext3

I have a Iomega Home Media Network Drive Cloud Edition 1TB that started clicking and then displayed a failure LED code Power LED and Red LED. I removed the SATA drive and inserted in a 'All in 1 HDD Docking Station' and connected to laptop by USB - Laptop has Win 7 OS. The dock is seen as drive E but cannot access and says 0% data etc. The drive does spin up when I power the dock.

Web searches say the drive has EXT3 file system and to use Ubuntu to access drive. I have now setup a dual boot laptop but still do not see the drive using ubuntu. Is there something else I need to do to get it recognised etc. I really would like to recover the data, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

Ext3 is like NTFS for Windows, it's THE Linux filesystem, so you shouldn't have any problem recovering your data with Ubuntu (or any other linux distribution).

If you don't see the disk maybe is becayse you are not looking in the right place ;)

First of all there are no drive letters in Linux: disk partitions (or more precisely the filesystem inside a partition) can be attached (mounted) anywere in the directory tree; generally the "non-system" partition are mounted into /media/{partition-label} or /media/{long-sequence-of-letters-and-numbers}.

If you can't see the content of the directories in /media/ you can try to launch the file manager as root (the administrator user) [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root)

If you still can't find your disk you can try to open a terminal and type:

```
cat /proc/partition
```

The table that is printed on the screen is a list of all disks and partitions that the OS has find in your computer: sda, sdb, sdc,... are the disks and sda1, sda2,... are the partitions inside inside sda disk. From the layout of the partitions you should be able to identify the disk you are looking for and you can try to mount the partition manually. From the terminal type:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /some/directory
```