# Deleting folders and files from a directory

Tags: directory, delete

How do you delete all folders and files in a directory and subdirectory?

Answer (score 2):

This command will remove directory and sub-directories

```
  rm -r directory_name
```

This command will remove forcely

```
  rm -rf directory_name
```

This command will remove the empty directory

```
  rmdir directory_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) you can do with this command:

```
rm -R <directory>
```

or

`sudo rm -R <directory>` (if you need root privileges for that directory)

where `<directory>` is the directory that you want to delete.

For more specifications about `rm` command run:

```
man rm
```

or

```
rm --help
```

Otherwise, in [Nautilus file manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager) - the default file manager in Ubuntu - select the directory that you want to delete and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> (to move it into Trash) or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> (to permanently delete). Also, you can see [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root) if you need root privileges for delete that directory.

Answer (score 0):

`rm -r /path/to/directory`

Be very careful with this command as if it is used incorrectly (with out directory argument) it can destroy your entire linux system. Be especially careful when using this command as root or with sudo. Another note, this is not completely secure and the file can be recovered with data reconstruction. If you would like to overwrite the file after it is unlinked use `shred`.

Comment: `-f` option is not necessary.

Comment: Ok I just looked that up, you're right. Thanks for the correction.