# "Open in terminal" not working on nautilus as root

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

When using natilus as root, open in terminal used to work as using with any user. However, when I press open in terminal when using nautilus as root now, it does nothing.

How to solve it?

The error:

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_data: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Comment: Do NOT use sudo with graphical aplications, especially Nautilus or any other file manager. It can break the userspace permissions quite easily. If you need to do then use *sudo -H nautilus* instead.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have to constantly make changes on /opt folder. Can I do it using -H?

Comment: Yes, you can and should even if it doesn't mess with permissions on system, root owned, folders. The problem is when you write something (as root) to the regular user(s) folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside any possible damage you've done via sudo nautilus command you could just install & use the nautilus extension `nautilus-admin`, requires restarting nautilus after install

`sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin`

It provides

`* Open as Administrator: opens a folder in a new Nautilus window
    running with administrator (root) privileges.
 * Edit as Administrator: opens a file in a Gedit window running
    with administrator (root) privileges.`

Does so thru a policykit policy.

Comment: It does not really answer my question, but it is a good solution.

Comment: As far as an answer - While sudo nautilus > open in terminal should open a root terminal @ dir. clicked on it's such poor behavior that figuring out why it 'broke' for you is pointless. Maybe from repeated indiscriminate use of sudo in instances it shouldn't be used? If I were you I'd check recursively  for root *owned*  files in your $HOME folder & address. `ls -lA -R  |grep root`

Comment: I now that I created many root owned files, but I also know how to revert it.