# Which best practice for using gedit as root?

Tags: gedit, gksudo, pkexec

`gksudo` seeming to be somehow depreciated since 2017 as I see on the [french forum documentation](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/gedit#edition_avec_privileges), is there an environment and version agnostic best practice allowing to use `gedit` as root?

(excluding `vim`, `nano` or `tee`: the use case being a GUI amendment of `sources.list` for instance)

My researchs brought me these proposals, are they equivalent or to be rejected :

- `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit`
- `gedit admin:///path/to/document`
- `sudo -i gedit`
- `sudo -H gedit`

Any other ?

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is gksu no longer installed by default?](https://askubuntu.com/a/284717/507051), the accepted answer to which explains a lot.

Comment: Your question makes an assumption... Best practice? Do not use elevated privileges with graphical applications at all.

Comment: I knom elevated privileges should be avoided in GUI, but that is not the use case I'm trying to answer. I didn't see compared analysis of the commands I ask for in the proposed duplicates.

Comment: The duplicates with answers of 2014 don't answer, the most recent question for wayland isn't exploring all commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73662/discussion-between-sudodus-and-nam1962).

Comment: I'm a recent fan of using `nautilus-admin` for file operations as `sudo` and to use `gedit` as sudo: https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root/868882#868882

Comment: That's elegant ! But also not environment agnostic