# How to open a text file in current working directory with `gedit admin://`?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gedit

The following terminal command will open the text file `ubuntu.css` from any location of a file structure:

```
$ gedit admin:///usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

However, if I am already in directory `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` and I want to open the file `ubuntu.css` with `gedit`, how should I submit the above  command without having to type the full path again?

**Edit:**
I am adding [a link here](https://techstop.github.io/open-file-as-root/) that I just found that give a short intro to the above command. But it does not deal with the issue that I have identified in my question.

Comment: "gedit ubuntu.css" worked for me. If you want to edit file then use "sudo gedit ubuntu.css"

Comment: @SHAHS I thought we should move away from using `sudo gedit` and instead should move to use `gedit admin:`. Hence, I would like to better understand how to use the `gedit admin:` syntax. Are you able to help?

Comment: If you do use `sudo` then use `sudo -H gedit ubuntu.css`. The `-H` option solves the problem of messed up your personal gedit config files caused by using plain `sudo`.

Comment: @user68186 I noticed that the fonts sizes in gedit buttons and title bar appears different ( and not so proportionate) when using `sudo -H gedit` as compared to `gedit admin://`.

Comment: I don't know why the fonts size in the buttons and title bar would be different. Unless you have some customization of gedit config that is ignored when you use `-H` option.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME User Theme Extension activated. I did not customise `gedit` preferences specifically. In any case, I am looking towards better understanding how to use `gedit admin://` w/o  typing the full path when I am already in the cwd with `ubuntu.css`. Can you point the way to answer my question or that can help better understand the `admin`  command? I can't find references that explain `admin`. I have noticed that it uses `pkexec` to open the file. This is unlike `sudo`.

Comment: I don't know enough about `pkexec` and the `admin://` prefix to answer your question. I tried a few variation of what you are trying to do and they didn't work for me either. So, I can't answer your question.

Comment: I'm not on gnome, so I can't test it, but I would expect `gedit admin://$(pwd)/ubuntu.css` to work. If it works you could easily create an alias or wrapper script to make it even easier to use.

Comment: @LienhartWoitok Thanks. It works! Can you write it up as an answer and provide a link/reference to explain how to use the `admin ://` cmd (if you can)? I will accept it thereafter. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually @vanadium improved on my initial idea and also provided a script. Apart from a minor formatting edit I have nothing of significance to add to his answer. Feel free to accept his answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, it is not possible to pass a relative path with this `admin://` URI. This answer may be disappointing, but that is how it currently (Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 19.10) works.

**Using a short wrapper script**

You can, however, very conveniently work around the issue with a wrapper script. With the script `sedit`, you edit a file correctly with administrator privileges, just by typing the command and a filename, as in `sedit ubuntu.css`.

`sedit`):

````
```bash
#!/bin/bash
gedit admin://$(readlink -f "$1")
```
````

If you place that in a folder in your path, the command `sedit ubuntu.css` will open the file using the admin URI. Also providing the full path, or any valid path, will work.

**Other options**

Other, more standard options to not to have to type the pathname are:

- You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> expansion once you typed the three slashes of the URI.
- You could drag the file from Files (nautilus) into the terminal. Thus, you could type "gedit admin://' in the terminal, find the file in Files, and then drag the file from Files into the terminal. This can make it easier to enter the URI in the terminal.
- You could avoid typing the path using `$(pwd)filename` or `$(readlink -f filename)`.

  ```
  gedit admin://$(pwd)/ubuntu.css
  ```

  or

  ```
  gedit admin://$(readlink -f ubuntu.css)`
  ```
- You can install the nautilus python extension, `nautilus-admin`. Install it with the command `sudo apt install nautilus-admin` or using Synaptic Package manager (unfortunatelly, you cannot find it using Software). This small python extension integrates in the right-click menu, and converts the selected file to an 'admin://' URI for editing with root permissions.

Comment: Bummer.... ;( Btw, can you provide a reference/hyperlink to elaborate on the `admin://` command in you answer? I can't find it.

Comment: @SunBear, didn't have more success than you did ;)

Comment: Thanks. Let me wait a few days. If no better answer, I will accept yours. ;) Really hoping there could be a shorter way of doing what I asked.

Comment: I also hope a better one pops up, but I doubt it ;)

Comment: I came up with a one-line script that could it have your way: "sedit ubuntu.css". Just put such script in your path and you are all set. Remains a workaround, though. You cannot specify relative admin:// URI's as I said from the start.

Comment: `$(pwd)` appears to be the relative path symbol. If so, I think it is apt not to say  _"it is not possible to pass a relative path with this admin:// URI"_. Rather, your answer should say it is possible.

Comment: That is not correct. pwd prints the absolute path of the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `pwd` command for current directory

The `pwd` command returns the current directory so you can embed it in your command line:

```
gedit admin://$(pwd)/rootfilename
```

---

### Choose a different method

As this question [Which best practice for using gedit as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009574/which-best-practice-for-using-gedit-as-root) points out:

> My researchs brought me these proposals, are they equivalent or to be
>   rejected :
>
> - `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit`
> - `gedit admin:///path/to/document`
> - `sudo -i gedit`
> - `sudo -H gedit`

You are using option 2 but I prefer option 4 `sudo -H gedit` which allows relative path when editing a root owned file.

---

### Edit directly from Nautilus

If you are using Nautilus consider the extension [Edit as Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAqmQ.gif) which dramatically improves your workflow:

[image: nautilus admin.gif]

---

### Use your user profile for `gedit`

The problem with `gedit` as root is you loose your theme colors, font size, tab settings, line wrap settings, and plug-ins. I wrote a script called [`sgedit`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042344/i-need-an-equivalent-of-gksu-in-18-04/1100220#1100220) (sudo gedit) that solves that problem.

In the animation below the gedit plug-in shows thumbnail overview of document on the right pane. Grab the slider mini-window with a mouse <kbd>Left Click</kbd> and drag it down to quickly locate sections in the document.

Other user settings for theme, font size, line wrapping, tab stop settings, convert tabs to spaces, and all your regular user profile plug-ins are available when running as `sudo`.

[image: sgedit 80 column right slider.gif]

Comment: None of the `sudo` commands are valid to launch graphical applications as root. May not work in Wayland, moreover.  Nowadays there is a move to not run any graphical programs as root. Opening with the admin:// URI ensures that the application itself does not have to run with root privileges. I think the script I presented is then the simplest approach to work according to current standards in this respect. On the other hand, installing nautilus-admin may be a valid suggestion depending on how that one works.

Comment: @vanadium I'm on 16.04 and `admin//` is not supported there. In 2021 when 16.04 dies I'll probably convert to that method but in the mean time I like answers that work for all LTS versions. Many answers in AU  `sudo -H` is recommended.

Comment: "answers that work for all LTS versions" is very relative because it still depends on the user's configuration. "sudo -H" will not work on Wayland, for one thing. Moreover, this question relates to using admin:// and shortcutting the URL when you are in the directory where the file resides. Finally, it is not only about something working, but also about "best practices", and thus I would feel it is better not continue to steer to the old approaches that "work" but not necessarily are best practice.