# How to switch to gain root privileges in Nautilus file browser by typing in the addressbar in GUI while it's being used

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, gui, gvfs

I saw in a reddit comment that it was possible to switch to root user in nautilus file browser by just typing in a series of forward slashes and colons. I've since forgotten the sequence and searching the internet did not return any answers.

Is there an actual way to do that?

Comment: Hello, I've seen that question and I have read it. What I am asking is if there is a way to switch to root while using nautilus by just using the adressbar

Comment: what I wanted to do was to gain root priviledges, I've edited the question

Comment: There is the nautilus-admin  - Nautilus Admin is a simple Python extension for the Nautilus file manager
that adds some administrative actions to the right-click menu `sudo apt install nautilus-admin`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may want to use the GVfs admin backend, just add `admin://` to the beginning of the full path to your preferred directory.

Open Nautilus the usual way and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to enable typing in the address-bar, and then enter for example `admin:///usr/` to open the `/usr/` directory.

[image]

---

Alternatively, launch Terminal and run

```
nautilus admin:///
```

to open the `/` directory or

```
nautilus admin:///usr/
```

to open the `/usr/` directory etc.

Comment: Won't work with older Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have added a section about using GVFS backend in my answer to [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root/868882#868882)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the root folder `/` and double click the folder called `root`. Then, write your password two times and you'll get into the `root` folder. Then you can see `/` at the top of the screen. Click at that and now you are in a root instance of Nautilus.