# Permision to delete any file

Tags: permissions

There are two files in my Ubuntu 18.04, left after uninstallation od MyChrome app, I am not able to delete without change of permissions,as:

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mychrome_chrome.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/sequence/mychrome.json
```

There is no options to change permissions for that files. How to delete them?

Comment: You need administration previlage to delete these files. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root/868882#868882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are probably owned by the root user so your regular user is not allowed to remove them.  You should be able to open a terminal and then type `sudo rm -f /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mychrome_chrome.desktop` to remove the file.

If thay won't work, the file might be immutable (unlikely, but possible).  Try `sudo chattr -i /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mychrome_chrome.desktop` and then again `sudo rm -f /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mychrome_chrome.desktop`.

Comment: This answer was usefull, but with change of permissions privilage, see askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root/… – user68186