# How to open Nautilus as admin in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: usb, nautilus, administration, gksu

We have been cautioned not to use `sudo nautilus` to open Nautilus as root.

Have not been able to download `gksu` for 19.04.

Have also tried to install `nautilus-admin` to 19.04 without success.

Is it still possible to right click a file in Nautilus and select "open as administrator" in 19.04?

What to do?

Comment: have you also cautioned not to use `sudo -H nautilus`??

Comment: Are you using 19.10 or 19.04? 19.10 is off-topic.

Comment: I am using 19.10, will see what happens with 19.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root)

Comment: @user68186: With 16.04 you could use gksu to open nautilus as root, With 18.04 gksu was discontinued and nautilus-admin took it's place, with 19.04 nautilus-admin is not working I think I stick with the answer I gave on that page for bootable USB drives, but want to make sure I am doing it right.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan: Typo has been fixed, it is obviously about 19.04, what does it matter what I have tried?

Answer (score 4):

You may use the GVfs admin backend by adding `admin://` to the beginning of the full path to your preferred directory.

For example launch Nautilus and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to enable the address-bar, and then enter for example `admin:///` to open the `/` directory or `admin:///usr/` to open the `/usr/` directory.

Alternatively, launch Terminal and run

```
nautilus admin:///
```

to open the `/` directory or

```
nautilus admin:///usr/
```

to open the `/usr/` directory etc.

Comment: With 18.04 we could right click and select "open as administrator" in Nautilus, is this still possible?

Comment: Not sure about that. This answer was written for [the initial version of the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1171784/1).

Comment: @C.S.Cameron You need to install the plug-in for "open as administrator". I'll reboot after this movie and try it out in 19.04 upgraded from 16.04 later to see if it carried over from upgrade.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: nautilus-admin works fine for me with 18.04 but not with 19.04?

Comment: @pomsky: I think "open as administrator is a function of "nautilus-admin" and thus would be part of the original question.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I beg to differ, the [initial version](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1171784/1) simply asked "*How to open nautilus as admin in Ubuntu 19.10*". It mentioned things like `sudo nautilus`, `gksu` along with `nautilus-admin` and did not *explicitly* asked for the "right click and *'open as administrator'*" feature.

Comment: @pomsky: The question says/said "Have also tried to install nautilus-admin to 19.04 without success" and the title includes "How to open Nautilus as admin". nautilus-admin was also included as a Tag, I would expect nautilus-admin to be part of the question. Besides when I enter nautilus admin:/// in terminal I get warnings and errors.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll disengage. I don't think anything fruitful is going to come out of this.