# Ubuntu 20.04 super user for file manager

Tags: permissions

I tried "gksudo nautilus" in my terminal per the board instructions to get super user permissions in file manager and it is not working.  Any ideas?

Jay

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root)

Comment: `nautilus admin:///` or the `pkexec`-based method

Comment: Okay, I was able to get the super user status in the root directory but soon as I went into another directory to delete the files I was swithced back to a regular user.

Comment: I use `sudo -H nautilus` if I am using a Live USB. I install `nautilus-admin` if I am booting a Full install.

Comment: C.S.Cameron This did the trick!  Thanks!