# How to open terminal always with sudo privileges

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, gnome-terminal, administrator

I am wondering is there anyway to open terminal always with sudo privileges. And is there a way to open specific file with sudo privileges like windows have "run as administrator".

Comment: be careful what you wish for is the best advice...

Comment: What are you trying to say @24601

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root)

Comment: no@user68186 i am asking something else

Comment: There is a reason there is no "run as administrator" option in Linux. This reason is security. You don't *need* root privileges unless you change system settings, and you always need to type your password to do that. This keeps your system secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To always open a terminal as root is not a good idea, but, hey, it is your computer and we hope you will act responsibly.

Edit your `.bashrc` file and add `sudo -i` to the end. Then, anytime you launch the terminal, it will always start with the prompt for the [sudo] password, and drop you to a prompt with root privileges when you successfully entered the password.

With respect to opening a specific file, there is an extension for the file manager Files (aka nautilus) that allows to open a new file manager window, or edit a file with root privileges. It is available in the package `nautilus-admin`.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a perfectly valid answer to the question. Is it a security concern? Maybe, but not more than typing `sudo -i` as soon as you enter your terminal. Is this a bias because someone thinks they know better how a particular user should use their own system?