# How do I open and edit a usr/lib/udev file in 20.04 without root?

Tags: 20.04, gedit

How do I open and edit a `usr/lib/udev` file in Ubuntu 20.04 without root?

Comment: simple: you don't. That is why privileges exist.

Comment: You might be looking for this...`sudo gedit`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need root privileges to edit any files in that path.

You can use `sudo` before a command to obtain root privileges for a particular action.

For example:

```
sudo nano /path/to/file
```

This will open the file in the nano text editor as if you were root.

If you do not have sudo/root privileges, you will not be able to edit the file.  Contact your system administrator and describe to them why you need to edit these files.

Comment: I do not have a ststem administrator - it is my computer

Comment: Yes you do!  **You** are the system administrator. You can use `sudo`

Comment: Thank you everybody I thnk I have solved it now with all your help. I used su "username" to get root and find the directory then sudo gedit open and edit.The computer can now see the gps dongle I just have to go out in the cold to see if the dongle can see the satellites!