# Trying to access root folders through nautilus just brings me to "snap" folders [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS]

Tags: permissions, nautilus

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

So the purpose of this is rather silly... I just want to pull the preinstalled system wallpapers from **/usr/share/backgrounds** so I can pull them into GIMP and better recolor it to my purple UI coloring.

Where I'm finding issues... is accessing it via GUI applications. `sudo nautilus`, which I swear used to open to root, now opens to a folder where all I can see is a "snap" folder with no access to root.

While I would like a GUI way of doing this (let me make my own mistakes in my tinkerer's environment, for goodness sake), I'm open to terminal ways... just... again, I prefer a GUI method.

So far, I'd tried the aforementioned `sudo nautilus` to that result, also tried to use install dolphin and `sudo dolphin` but get `Executing Dolphin with sudo is not possible due to unfixable security vulnerabilities.`

I just want a GUI-accessible way to view these root folders.

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release details; but user GUI applications should generally not be run as root (ie. with `sudo`)  fyi:  you're probably viewing the `/root/` user directory and not what you expected

Comment: Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, edited into the post now. Forgive my question but why shouldn't GUI apps not be run as root? Is it just a security thing? As a power user, I think I should have the ability to see such areas, but also know when areas are dangerous to edit (i.e. Windows showing a warning when navigating into certain system folders).

It's the tinkerer in me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root)

Comment: There's no reason to use `sudo` for this - `nautilus admin:///usr/share/backgrounds` will let you access these files with superuser privileges while not actually running `nautilus` as root.

Comment: @muru Trying ```nautilus admin:///usr/share/backgrounds``` gives me an "Oops! something went wrong. Don't have permission to access the requested location." error. Also the ```gksu``` stuff seems to be outdated in jammy? idk

Comment: That's strabge. What about just `nautilus admin:///`?

Comment: @muru Same thing. Nautilus opens but spits a permissions error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136988/discussion-between-rabblerousergt-and-muru).

Comment: @GuntramBlohm No `nautilus` is not a *snap* package unless you're using Ubuntu Core (which is a *snap* only product of Ubuntu).  It's a *deb* package that is seeing a directory titled `snap` and you'll find the same in Debian with the same version of `nautilus` assuming you have the same directory names too.

Answer (score -1):

While I'm not sure if this is proper etiquette to answer my own question like this, I tried, to no avail, things like `nautilus admin:///` and hit a permission error.

**My solution was to install Nemo**, a Nautilus fork used in Linux Mint, which enables you to explore things using the "File System" tab on the left.

*One minor issue:* Just warning in case anyone goes this route, you'll have two "Files" apps in your app picker. ️ One is Nautilus, the other is Nemo.

Comment: For most users, `nautilus admin:///` will work properly and is easier than installing a whole new file manager.