# Ubuntu file manager not working

Tags: xubuntu, nautilus, files, filemanager

I tried running the `nautilus` command in the terminal, but the following error message popped up.

```
** (nautilus:9220): WARNING **: 15:17:57.478: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (nautilus:9220): WARNING **: 15:17:57.479: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `/root/` is the user directory for the *root* directory, and should be accessed. Are you using your Ubuntu user account? as that shouldn't be accessed if used as intended. Are you using Ubuntu? as the file-manager of Xubuntu is `thunar`?  and what release are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root)