# How can I link /home in a new install to the /home from an old install? Both are ubuntu 20.4

Tags: partitioning, ssd

Hx: I've been using various Linux versions since about 2001, settling on Ubuntu in 2010. Around 2020 I moved to new hardware with a 0.5TB SSD and 1.0TB HD. I put /home on the HD and the rest of ubuntu 20.04 on the SSD. This December I had 700GB of photos, videos, music, etc in the /home partition. Then the system seemed to crash, or in my bumbling around I trashed it.

I did a standard re-install of 20.04.3, with all of its partitions on the SSD leaving the HD and its older /home untouched. Now I want to redefine /home to use the HD again. I know I could do another re-install and put the /home partition on the HD, but that would mean 16+ hours of reloading /home from backup. And I wouldn't learn anything from that approach.

Is there a way of redefining /home? While I once made a good living with GW-BASIC, Pascal, and Perl, that was at a time before most of you who read this were born. Now in my 75th year I'm intimidated by the hashmark prompt, and I'm not understanding the answers I've found when googling about this.

### From Comments

I overwrote the old install with the new one. `gparted` reports this as `dev/sdb2`. The old `/home` partition is on `dev/sda2`. What I'm looking for is instructions on editing the `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want; I regularly re-install a system over another older GNU/Linux system, both making for example a Fedora or OpenSuSE system a Ubuntu system, keeping my old files (ie. /home) & setup (all configs etc), OR upgrade an older release (eg. 20.10 when it reached EOL) became a 21.10 system without losing my files, configs/setup etc. OR are you wanting to share /home between two OSes (that can be *risky* or *problematic* so I no longer do it!).  Changing from one system to another doesn't require losing what was there beforehand with Ubuntu! but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: FYI:   I'd answer @user68186 point first if that's what you want & get an answer he/she is willing to write (ie. make your `/home` point to HDD using *live* media etc), but I'll provide a link to https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533 if you're interested in *learning* about re-install options... (It's very wordy sorry) though that detail is found 30+ times here on this site as I mention it often like prior comment.

Comment: I overwrote the old install with the new one. gparted reports this as dev/sdb2. The old /home partition is on dev/sda2. What I'm looking for is instructions on editing the /etc/fstab file.

Comment: to userguiverc: thanks. I think that user68186 approach will probably work. To everyone: apologies for being too long and prolly riding roughshod over the forum protocols.

Comment: When adding additional details; please edit your question & add the additional or corrected detail there.  This is a Q&A site & not a forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/ is where Ubuntu Forums are).  Comments are intended to be just *comments* or questions/queries seeking clarification from the *Original Poster* (OP) and get deleted once addressed.  Answers are to your initial question itself.  (FYI: my mention of *wordy* was in relation to the link I provided & my *opus* or wordy answer... not your question; old[ish] & brain injury (me) aren't a great mix..)

Comment: If the answer worked for you, don't forget to mark it as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✓next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others. If the answer didn't work, I would like to know and fix the answer if possible.

Answer (score 2):

## Backup! Backup!! Backup!!!

Backup all your important files and folders. It seems you already have backups but this needs repeating for anyone who may be reading this answer later.

## Find the UUID

UUIDs are Universally Unique IDentifiers. You need to find the UUD for the old `/home` partition. Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo blkid
```

You will see a bunch of output among it you will find a line like:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="26810f5a-83c7-4184-8bba-dafc9684fe73" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bb712651-dcf5-4ca4-aac1-cd225fec9b7f"
```

Note the first part `/dev/sda2`. This should match the `/home` partition in the HDD. Copy the part that looks like `UUID="26810f5a-83c7-4184-8bba-dafc9684fe73"` and save it in a file. The actual numbers and letters of the UUID for you will be different. **Do not copy the UUID from this answer.**

## Edit the `/etc/fstab`

### Make a backup copy

Before editing the `/etc/fstab` make a backup copy:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.original
```

Now if things go wrong you should be able to get back to the original `fstab`.

### Edit the file

Open the file `/etc/fstab` in a text editor of your choice. You will need the `sudo` prefix or [Edit as an Administrator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root/868882#868882) option in the context menu. For example, you can use the `nano` editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

At the end of the file add a couple of lines like:

```
# /home was on /dev/sda2 during past installation
UUID=26810f5a-83c7-4184-8bba-dafc9684fe73 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

The first line is a comment to remind you what the next line is for. **Do not copy** `26810f5a-83c7-4184-8bba-dafc9684fe73`. Replace it with the UUID you have found and saved earlier.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the changes followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>  to exit `nano`.

## Restart your computer

If you have used the same `username` in your new installation as you did in your old installation, and if all went well, you should have your old `/home` back.

Hope this helps