# Is there a GUI program to securely delete files and folders?

Tags: gui, delete, permanent-delete, secure-erase

I see there's a lot of info in the answers to [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/q/57572/47206) question.

I have used such **CLI commands added to the context menu of the file manager** (mostly Thunar's custom actions, which I favour over Nautilus, while I am in Xfce).

**What I want here is a GUI** program (although I imagine that the same or similar commands like `wipe` and `srm` would be used) because I prefer to have some kind of **visible image and control over the process** (I want a GUI **not only for running the command, but for the entire process, one that maybe would display percentage, possibility of stopping the process, various settings listed**, etc.)

In Windows there a are a lot of such (free) programs, most probably there are some in Linux too.

Comment: Try wipe extension for nautilus

Comment: @Tachyons: I guess you mean file manager context menu commands. I do not use Nautilus, but I use a lot of those in Thunar, where they are called 'custom actions'. But what I am asking here is a GUI, as clearly stated in the question body

Comment: Bleachbit does do what you want: it has a gui, which has a progress bar so you can monitor the deletion process, and you can select any files and folders to delete, as I explain [in my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/267805/how-to-use-bleachbit-to-remove-completely-any-selected-file-or-folder)

Comment: @Mik: given that Bleachbit does what I ask my question here is a duplicate of the older one: http://askubuntu.com/q/57572/47206 (not the more specific one that you answered, until you move your answer there). My idea is to put your answer there. I'll close this as duplicate.

Comment: It's simple then: this question here should be closed as the duplicate, and the one I answered, which is very very specifically about bleachbit, should be kept open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bleachbit** is the answer, as presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/267839/47206). Therefore, this is a duplicate of the older more general [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/57572/47206). Any possible answers to this question here can be posted there, while specifying that a GUI is involved.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have something similar to the nautilus context menu entry you can try with the extension: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-wipe/

Comment: what is the point of posting a bleachbit link that is already present in the question? also in the question body: 'I have used such CLI commands added to the context menu of the file manager but I want a GUI etc'

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I forgot to delete it out of the answer, after I read the question a second time I saw Bleachbit was mentioned. Sorry.

Comment: I hope your answer is useful to others. I do not use nautilus (but thunar in xfce) and, as specified in the question, I want something more than file manager context menu commands: I want a GUI. In case you stumble into such a thing, please revisit your answer here

Comment: Note: you will need to [restart nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/19981) after installing the extension to see the "wipe" menu option.