# How to use BleachBit to remove completely any selected file or folder?

Tags: files, secure-erase, bleachbit

The BleachBit [website](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/documentation/shred-files-wipe-disk) states that the program can *"Overwrite specific files found anywhere on the hard drive"*.

Can I select a file and shred it with BB or do I have to delete it first the normal way and then wipe the empty space to avoid recovery?

I may not want all my empty space wiped or I may not have the time for that.

The program displays a list of programs, as well as a 'Bash' and a 'Deep scan' option.

[image]

It looks it is intended to scan for files that are already hidden or deleted. But what about selecting a specific file/folder and wiping it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard version of `Bleachbit` installed from the repositories (version 0.9.1 for 12.04) has exactly the functionality you want. You can simply run the program, click *File* on the Menu and you will be given options to select files or folders to shred.

[image]

Clicking 'Shred Files' or 'Shred Folders' will open a file browser and allow you to navigate to what you want to remove.

[image]

**Note:** I recommend that you don't run `bleachbit` with elevated privileges, like `gksudo bleachbit` or use the provided menu entry to do so, as a mistake could be very costly!

For more information, see `man bleachbit` or the [official website](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net), which details the development of the program and how now it has reached version 0.9.5 (Jan 2013).