# What to do when the Options button ("Cog wheel") disappears in nautilus from the upper-right corner - pb re-occurs

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I noticed that sometimes the "Cog Wheel"  - Options button (I do not know if it is the proper translation from French) at the most up-right corner disappears in nautilus (see attached image)
Without Option button : 
[image: Nautilus Options]

With Option button :
[image: Nautilus Options 2]

I tried to stop and restart Nautilus via the "nautilus -q && nautilus &" command found in the following  [How to restart nautilus without logging out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19979/how-to-restart-nautilus-without-logging-out)
but this DOES NOT make the Options button re-appear.

In the contrary it gives me the following error message :

> nautilus -q && nautilus & 
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ex3v.png) 4700 laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:~$
>   Impossible d'enregistrer l'application:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not
>   receive a reply (timeout by message bus)

Which can be translated to "Impossible to register the application : ..."

The only workaround I found is to restart ubuntu which is not an acceptable solution (even closing and opening the session doesn't solve this problem).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Laurent

[Edit 1] : I confirm that after a crash of Nautilus I do not see the Option Button anymore as described above and I have to restart .

And when I issue the command "nautilus -q && nautilus" I still receive the message

laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:~$ nautilus -q && nautilus

Impossible d'enregistrer l'application:

GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)

[Edit 2] : after all latest updates applied I now DO NOT have the Options Button in Nautilus even after a Ubuntu restarted from fresh.

This is REALLY annoying because this button allows for example to automatically select files from formating rules (+ invert the selection) and many other power full options).

Any idea ?

The problem re-occurs after latest Ubuntu updates and restart (on August 6th 2015)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what addon you have that adds the settings cog wheel, but you can get to the options with edit -> preferences menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer NoBugs. I do not think I have installed any special addon over my 14.04 LTS configuration. I'll try your trick next time the problem occurs and come back to you.

Comment: After checking tHe Edit -> Preferences menu DOES NOT offer me to get this Options Button

Comment: Where did your options button come from? I never see it on my 14.04.

Comment: The top screen is what one would see in an `ubuntu` session, the bottom one what could be in a `gnome-session`. (- There is also be an X button for gnome-session here.) 
All the options in the cog & view buttons should be in the nautilus menus available with mouse over the Unity panel in 14.04. What is missing in both screens is window decoration, is that the way the windows are or just in screens?

Comment: Sorry but I do not know the difference between a Ubuntu session and a gnome-session. The thing I checked is that echo $DESKTOP_SESSION gives me ubuntu. I just speak about the Cow wheel that becomes unavailable (not about windows decoration)

Comment: Cow wheel? Is this feature some easter-egg of the `apt-get moo` type?