# How to debug Nautilus crashes and issues?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, gnome-classic

I have a problem since the last update: Nautilus mysteriously doesn't start properly. I see it is a systems wide problem, i.e. affecting all the users on my host. Nevertheless, I have tried:

1. clean ~/.gconf folder
2. clean ~/.config folder

But nothing seems to cure the issue.

As a **temporary workaround** I can:

```
killall nautilus
nautilus -q
nautilus
```

Then wait for a few tens of seconds, no error displayed, and nautilus starts.

In the process I get:

```
andy@Andy-HyperTop14$ nautilus -q
Initializing nautilus-image-converter extension
sys:1: Warning: Source ID 273 was not found when attempting to remove it
sys:1: Warning: Source ID 274 was not found when attempting to remove it
sys:1: Warning: Source ID 275 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

I don't understand this output.

This seems to be a common problem flagged in: [How to restart nautilus without logging out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19979/how-to-restart-nautilus-without-logging-out)

**Question 1** Where are the Nautilus related errors logged? I have looked in

```
/var/log
```

But nothing can be connected to Nautilus from there.

**Question 2** Is there a way to run the tool in "debug mode"?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution I found from the [GNOME website](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingGNOME). Simply set the environmental variables before launching `nautilus`, *i.e.*:

```bsh
G_DEBUG="all" NAUTILUS_DEBUG="All" nautilus
```

Logs can be captured from the terminal output.

Comment: Prefer `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all`