# Text disappeared/turned white in File Manager

Tags: nautilus, display, text

This problem happened already some times to me. It is fixed with a reboot, but I am wondering if there is a faster solution.

Windows in File Manager look like this:

[image: File Manager Window with white text]

Answer (score 0):

My nautilus doesn't used to respond So for restarting I used
nautilus -q or killall nautilus

[How to restart nautilus without logging out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19979/how-to-restart-nautilus-without-logging-out)

But both the commands didn't worked for me

So I killed the process manually and it worked for me without restarting my system

ps -ef | grep nautilus

kill -9 ID

you can try both to see if it helps whenever you are facing the issue again

Comment: That doesn't work. I recognized that also the menus in all unity windows (also application windows) are without the text. Perhaps it is another thing to restart?

Comment: I thought its nautilus only
(Incase you haven't found this) See this link looks like its a bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1573959

Also temporary workaround was also there in the comment 

Switching between terminal 

ALT+CTRL+F1 then ALT+CTRL+F7

Comment: Thanks, that bug seems to clearly describe my problem. I tried the kernel update. Let's see. In the meanwhile I rebooted and the error is not easily reproducible for me. Let's see.