# Folders Colors does not works after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, nautilus-extensions

I'm tying to change a folder color or add a emblem and nothing happen, in logs i can see the following error:

```
GLib.Error: g-io-error-quark: Error setting file metadata: can’t open metadata tree (0)
   File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/folder-color.py", line 140, in restore_color
    self.restore_color(item_path)
  File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/folder-color.py", line 96, in set_color
    self.foldercolor.set_color(item_path, self._get_skel_folder(item_path, icon)['name'])
 File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/folder-color.py", line 316, in _menu_activate_color
```

on the other hand, change a folder icon does not works too, I'm not sure if it's related.

Comment: Maybe related: on 18.04 having `RuntimeError: object at 0x7fba413dcf00 of type FolderColorMenu is not initialized`. Just removed `folder-color` package and [restart nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/19981/349837). Everything fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use scripts for 17.04 (unity) on 17.10 (gnome) without altering all the code to function with gnome.

`/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/folder-color.py` lines 140, 96, and 316 probably contain an instruction that is Unity related.

What version are you using? The one from here https://launchpad.net/folder-color does not have a `restore_color` nor a line 96. Can you add the lines from your version? (and maybe a few above and below it). Maybe it is an easy edit.

Comment: Version: **0.0.86-0ubuntu1**, I'm trying remove, reinstalling and restarting nautilus but nothing happen :(

Answer (score 0):

It has an easy fix; type these in your terminal, one at a time:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costales/folder-color
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install folder-color
nautilus -q
```

Now if you launch your nautilus via terminal, you won't see any RunTimeError